# How to make span class invisible untill it is triggerd?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made two span classes in one "li" tag , I want them to toggle when I press the button , the problem I'm getting is that they both are appearing and my JS is not working , I have checked my js on jsfiddle also but there is no error appearing

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SbsR/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".smiley").click(function () {


    if ($('button').clicked) {
        $('.off').css('display' ,'true');
        $('.on').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.off').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: What is `if ($('button').clicked)` doing?

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

**Following are mistakes in your fiddle:**

(1) You missed to **add jQuery library** available at the top left in jsfiddle.

(2) There is nothing like `display: off` instead use `display: none`

```
$('.off').css('display' ,'off');  //wrong
```

(3) There is no class called `.smiley` in your code.

```
$(".smiley").click(function () { //wrong and unnecessary
```

(4) Nothing like this available

```
if ($('button').clicked) { //wrong and unnecessary
```

(5) You need to learn more about ***selector*** [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

I have tuned your code like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").on('click', function () {
        $('.toggle').toggle();
    });
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3SbsR/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3SbsR/4/)

You didn't include jquery and your script was all janky.  I cleaned it up to work how I think you want it to after reading your question.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('.switching_spans').toggleClass('on');
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="fiddle">
    <span class="switching_spans">1</span>
    <span class="switching_spans on">!</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.switching_spans {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:blue;
}
.on{
    background:green;
}
```